# How do I prevent the addition of an extra column when I write a CSV with C#?

Tags: c#, csv

I found and tweaked some C# code to remove embedded double quotes from some CSV files. I don't use C# very much, so I'm not sure why the code is adding an extra column to the original CSV. I'm assuming it has something to do with the WriteAllLines method. I printed out the CSV headings:

```
Index([u'State', u'Birthdate', u'Never Contact Type', u'Opt In Marketing',
   u'Pref. Contact Type', u'Individual Source', u'Individual Status',
   u'Individual Sub Type', u'Individual Type', u'Address 1', u'Address 2',
   u'City', u'Company', u'County', u'Email Address', u'First Name',
   u'Last Name', u'Mobile Number', u'Home/Main Number', u'Postal Code',
   u'Salutation', u'Work Number', u'Assigned To', u'Purchase Date',
   u'Entity Id', u'Event Id', u'Sales Sub Type', u'Sales Type',
   u'Sales Source', u'Sales Status', u'Tracking Code',
   u'DMS Deal/RO Number', u'Deal Date', u'Insert Date', u'Update Date',
   u'Make', u'Model', u'Series', u'Stock Num', u'Style', u'VIN Number',
   u'Year', u'Unnamed: 42']
```

As you can see there is a last column that is added when I run this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"some_filepath";
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);


        foreach(string file in files)
        {
            if (file.EndsWith(".csv"))
            {
                var fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                var fileContentUpdated = fileContent.Select(x => new Regex(@"(?<!^)(?<!\,)""(?!\,)(?!$)").Replace(x, "'")).ToArray();
                File.WriteAllLines(file, fileContentUpdated);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What's on the line with the extra comma? If it's not quoting fields properly, then `Fred Smith, Jr.` will be TWO cells in the csv, not one.

Comment: @MarcB I checked that. But there is no data in the extra column, so I don't think it's that.

Comment: Open your csv in any text editor to make sure that the row does not end with a COMMA

Comment: Can you show the output you get.

Comment: @AshutoshVyas That was it. I guess I never noticed that in the other CSV files.

Comment: Have you considered wrapping your fields in quotes?  That should allow for embedded commas, you just need to escape any quotes you actually need in the output.

Comment: @BradleyUffner The fields are already wrapped in quotes. I don't think embedded commas is the problem, because the last column has no data in it, which I noticed when I opened it in Excel and when I opened it in a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the same comment as answer for you to mark it.

> Open your csv in any text editor to make sure that the row does not
>   end with a COMMA

Comment: Just for further info, I have tested this on about 200 CSVs I was having problems with and it worked. I decided to write a Python script, since I'm more familiar with that language to remove commas that proceeded the return `\r` characters at the end of every line. Works like a charm. If anyone is willing to share a script that does the same thing in C#, I would be very grateful.